# Installing 'DiffNet' package gives, compilation error in R

Tags: r, compiler-errors, installation, package

I am trying to install the `DiffNet` package in R after downloading it (http://mukherjeelab.nki.nl/highdimtwo/index.html) but get this message:

```
(* installing *source* package 'DiffNet' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="DiffNet.dll" OBJECTS="betamat_diffnet.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'DiffNet'
* removing 'C:/Users/difeuser/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/DiffNet'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\difeuser\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" "C:/Users/difeuser/Downloads/DiffNet_1.0(2).tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/difeuser/Downloads/DiffNet_1.0(2).tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status)
```

I tried to copy-paste it in the library folder in R directly but it is still not recognized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset)?

Comment: I downloaded the package and installed one dependency that was required. I can't say if there are specific instructions. I just downloaded and tried to install it from the download folder by selecting 'select package from archive' .taz etc. However, it gave me the above error.

Comment: The above error (attached with question) is produced in RStudio. When I tried in R directly, I got this error (Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'DiffNet_1.0(1).tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory')